# error en python

Tags: python

estaba haciendo un bot de Discord con Python y al usar el comando de busqueda de YouTube me da el error "IndexError: list index out of range".
Este seria el codigo:

```
@bot.command()
async def yt(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({'search_query': search})
    html_content = request.urlopen('http://www.youtube.com/results?' + query_string)
    search_results = re.findall('href=\"\\/watch\\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode())
    print(search_results)
    await ctx.send('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + search_results[0])
```

Comment: Posiblemente `findall()` te ha retornado una lista vacía, por lo que al intentar acceder a su elemento `[0]`, ya que no existe, obtienes el error que has observado.

Comment: se puede arreglar de alguna manera? ya que mi busqueda de test si aparece en youtube

Comment: tiene pinta de estar mal la expresión regular. ¿Por qué tanto \\? ¿cómo es la cadena que intentas encajar? Quizás la siguiente te sirva `re.findall('href="/watch?v=(.{11})', ...)`

Comment: ya lo intente y no, me tira el mismo error

Comment: Y cómo es la cadena que intentas buscar? La expresión regular que estás usando obviamente no encaja con lo que buscas, ya que te devuelve una lista vacía.